# validation of input type using scanf returned value has failed

Tags: c

i want to check if all inputs are of type double in this code in c by using the returned value of scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a,b,c;
    int x = scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

but this is what i'm getting:

- here i expect 1 but i'm getting 0: 
  [image]
- here i expect 2 but i'm getting 1:
  [image]

Comment: Don't post images or links to external sites - the in and output are plain text copy it into the question

Comment: And explain *why*  you expect these outputs

Comment: `scanf` will fail on first failed conversion. Your expectations are not justified.

Comment: `scanf` returns  `zero in the event of an early matching failure.` That is what happened with your first run. `scanf` worked as designed contrary to your expectation.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `scanf` does not fail on the first failed conversion. `scanf` returns (and hence stops processing) when a directive fails. `scanf` works properly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, I noticed this inaccuracy when it was too late to edit.

Comment: @Ameen Qadi After the `printf("%d", x);`, Try `if (x < 3) { int ch = getchar(); printf("<%c>\n", ch);  }` to see what is left in `stdin` after a "failure".  The result will be informative.

Answer (score 2):

According to [scanf man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives which describe
>   how to process the sequence of input characters. If processing of a
>   directive fails, no further input is read, and scanf() returns

---

Thus

For Case 1.

`scanf` will stops reading when it detects the mismatch for the first specifier.

For Case 2.

`scanf` will stops reading when it detects the mismatch for the second specifier.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` stops processing input as soon as any conversion fails, going from left to right, it doesn't try to process the remaining inputs.

So when you enter

```
b b 2.8
```

it fails when trying to do the first `%lf` conversion. Since no conversions have been done, it returns `0`.

When you enter

```
2 x 2.1
```

it successfully converts `2` to a `double`, but fails on `x`, so it doesn't process `2.1` and returns `1`.